# TexForm with fractional overall factor

Tags: output-formatting, latex

I am having some trouble with TeXForm output. Basically, I have many expressions that have an overall fractional factor, like `1/(16 Pi^2)`, in front. However, whenever I put the expression into `TeXForm`, it puts the entire expression in the form `\frac{numerator}{16 Pi^2}`. I was wondering if there is any way to force the overall factor to stay in front, without making one giant fraction.

A small example:

```
1/Pi Total[x^Range[10]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
TeXForm[%]

\frac{x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x}{\pi }
```

Comment: can you provide a MWE?

Comment: I'm not sure this has much to do with `TexForm` - the default output shows the same behavior of putting everything onto a single fraction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea that might work for you (without any example, I can only guess...):

```
expr = 1/(16 Pi^2) (a + b + c);

TeXForm[
 Times @@ (
   HoldForm /@ Times @@@
     GatherBy[List @@ expr, MatchQ[_Rational | Power[_, _?Negative]]]
   )
 ]
(* \frac{1}{16 \pi ^2} (a+b+c) *)
```

To see where this is coming from, let's take a look at the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of the expression:

```
FullForm@expr
(* Times[Rational[1,16],Plus[a,b,c],Power[Pi,-2]] *)
```

The idea is now to take the expression and group into two groups - one for anything that is either a rational number or a negative power and the rest:

```
GatherBy[List @@ expr, MatchQ[_Rational | Power[_, _?Negative]]]
(* {{1/16, 1/π^2}, {a + b + c}} *)
```

Multiplying the terms together and wrapping them in [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) looks like this:

```
Times @@ (
  HoldForm /@ Times @@@
    GatherBy[List @@ expr, MatchQ[_Rational | Power[_, _?Negative]]]
  )
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great! super cool method

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this:

```
expr = 1/Pi Total[x^Range[10]];
Through[{Numerator, Denominator}[expr]] /. {n_, d_} :> TeXForm@HoldForm[HoldForm[1/d] n]
```

> $$\frac{1}{\pi }
>    \left(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8+x^9+x^{10}\right)$$